# Awk matchings/joining two files for which 1 is a variable

Tags: awk

Hi all I have made awk work fine using two physical files:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { _[$1]=$2 } NR!=FNR { if(_[$2] != "") print $0"  "_[$2]}' codes.txt text.txt
```

What I am trying to do:  Rather than use physical files use a variable instead for 2nd file..

```
awk 'NR==FNR { _[$1]=$2 } NR!=FNR { if(_[$2] != "") print $0"  "_[$2]}' codes.txt $variable
```

since I am having to export out the results to a physical file then using this command to map the other files values with the first file...

I have tried

```
echo $variable|awk 'NR==FNR { _[$1]=$2 } NR!=FNR { if(_[$2] != "") print $0"  "_[$2]}' codes.txt
```

which has not worked :(

As asked here is the example:

```
cat text.txt 
564 ERR0001
535 ERR0002

 cat codes.txt 
ERR0001 This_is_error_1
ERR0002 This_is_error_2

 awk 'NR==FNR { _[$1]=$2 } NR!=FNR { if(_[$2] != "") print $0"  "_[$2]}' codes.txt text.txt 
564 ERR0001  This_is_error_1
535 ERR0002  This_is_error_2

 awk 'NR==FNR { _[$1]=$2 } NR!=FNR { if(_[$2] != "") print $0"  "_[$2]}' codes.txt text.txt |tr "_" " "
564 ERR0001  This is error 1
535 ERR0002  This is error 2
```

---

here is the failure:

```
gg=$(cat text.txt)

echo $gg
564 ERR0001 535 ERR0002

awk 'NR==FNR { _[$1]=$2 } NR!=FNR { if(_[$2] != "") print $0"  "_[$2]}' codes.txt $gg |tr "_" " "
awk: (FILENAME=codes.txt FNR=2) fatal: cannot open file `564' for reading (No such file or directory)

IFS=' ';
echo $gg
564 ERR0001
535 ERR0002

awk 'NR==FNR { _[$1]=$2 } NR!=FNR { if(_[$2] != "") print $0"  "_[$2]}' codes.txt $gg |tr "_" " "
awk: (FILENAME=codes.txt FNR=2) fatal: cannot open file `564' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

As suggested join:

```
join -1 2 -2 1 text.txt codes.txt 
ERR0001 564 This_is_error_1
ERR0002 535 This_is_error_2

join -1 2 -2 1 $gg codes.txt 
join: extra operand `ERR0002'
Try `join --help' for more information.

echo $gg
564 ERR0001
535 ERR0002
```

answered by tripleee

```
echo $gg|join -1 2 -2 1 -  codes.txt 
ERR0001 564 This_is_error_1
ERR0002 535 This_is_error_2

 echo $gg|awk 'NR==FNR { _[$1]=$2 } NR!=FNR { if(_[$2] != "") print $0"  "_[$2]}' codes.txt - |tr "_" " "
564 ERR0001  This is error 1
535 ERR0002  This is error 2
```

Comment: I've no idea what you're talking about. Post some sample input and expected output.

Comment: does the 2nd code block in your question work?

Comment: @ kent nope it didn't work

Comment: Ed I have updated the question with some examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `echo` the variable and pipe it to any command which reads standard input.

For what it's worth, many Unix utilities accept a file name argument `-` to mean standard input.

```
echo "$gg" | sort | join -1 2 -2 1 - text.txt
```

Recent versions of Bash also have the `<<<"$gg"` here-string operator.

Comment: Thanks Tripleee - I have used pipes for tarring or netcatting and using tar together but failed to think of it for this scenario - thanks again - works great

Answer (score 0):

There [is a command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) that will just do this for you:

```
$ join -1 2 -2 1 text.txt codes.txt
```

Comment: It requires both input files to be sorted on the joiner field.